# How to create dynamic consumer tasks for a Producer-Consumer solution using thread pools?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a Producer-Consumer solution.

But I don't want to use a fixed number of consumer Threads. Instead I want to create a new Consumer Thread if my eventQueue is full.

I have created an ExecutorService but since I got only one EventConsumerTask instance, It creates only a single thread for this task.

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<String> eventQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(50);

ExecutorService es = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 20, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());

es.execute(new EventConsumerTask(eventQueue));
```

Here is my EventConsumerTask;

```
public class EventConsumerTask implements Runnable{

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> eventQueue;

    public EventConsumerTask(LinkedBlockingQueue<String> eventQueue){
        this.eventQueue = eventQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                String event = eventQueue.take();
                System.out.println(event);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [cached Thread Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool())?

Comment: Same issue as with xingbin's answer, won't add more EventConsumerTasks

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the concept. It's rather silly though, why would you only start concurrently processing the tasks after a threshold, rather than just having a set amount of threads that just handle the single events one by one off a single queue?

Comment: It could be quite reasonable, but only if you can scale up **and** down.

Comment: No, I did not downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to spawn another EventConsumerTask when the queue is full? I think, there will be a method where you fill the queue, so you could trigger it there:

```
    public synchronized void add(String item){
    if(eventQueue.remainingCapacity() == 0)
    {
        es.execute(new EventConsumerTask(eventQueue)); 
    }
    waitUntilQueueHasCapacityAgain();
    eventQueue.add(item);
}
```

If you store the EventConsumerTask e.g. in a list, you could scale down your executors/threads again, if the queue is getting empty.

Btw.

- You don't need Thread.sleep(), from the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()): queue.take() *Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.*
- A [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) will do a similar same job without locking, there you'd want to sleep, bot only when no item is available, rather than after every item.

Comment: Honestly, the answer of @danui looks more canonical to me, if it the `Thread.sleep(1000);` would not be there. Nowadays I'd look for some reactive solution, but that implies that you have some asynchronous interface supplying your data.

Comment: Check out this on http processing with [reactive streams](https://blog.codefx.org/java/reactive-http-2-requests-responses/), they are there since java 9.

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is dynamic.

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue)) of:

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor​(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)
```

> corePoolSize - the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they
>   are idle, unless allowCoreThreadTimeOut is set
>
> maximumPoolSize - the
>   maximum number of threads to allow in the pool

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 20, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

This means the thread pool can hold 60 threads at most.

Comment: I don't think, it answers to his reqirement, it won't add further EventConsumerTasks

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I'd suggest this general pattern:

```
// single thread to take from the event and dispatch handling to the pool
ExecutorService submitter = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
// 5 - 20 threads for the individual event handlers, as suggested by xingbin
ExecutorService pooledExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor (5, 20, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());

submitter.submit(() -> {
    while (true) {
        String event = eventQueue.take();
        // submit handling of the individual events in the pool
        pooledExecutor.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println(event);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
});
```